# VB.Net Datagridview loop though selection and update column in same database is only updating the first selected?

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, datagridview, bartender

I am trying to update the values in a database based on multi-selected in a datagridview via the a button. 
I do all my SQL commands via a Class called SQLControl to keep the code clean.

My Problem is the last selected row isn't getting updated to the database even though I can see all selected rows values get updated in the datagridview.

```
Private Sub UpdateData()

    Dim rowcount As Integer = dgvData.SelectedRows.Count - 1
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvData.SelectedRows


        dgvData.Rows(row.Index).Cells(9).Value = 1


        dgvData.Rows(row.Index).Cells(10).Value = System.DateTime.Now


    Next
    SQL.DBDA.UpdateCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(SQL.DBDA).GetUpdateCommand
    SQL.DBDA.Update(SQL.DBDT)

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you distill your code sample down to just the code in question? For example, all those Key and Button handlers distract from the actual problem.

Comment: The code in question is the "LabelPrint()" Sub

Comment: dgvData.Rows(row.Index).Cells(9).Value = 1 and dgvData.Rows(row.Index).Cells(10).Value = System.DateTime.Now    .... these only update the first row selected.

Comment: Why index Rows when you are already iterating them? Can you replace `dgvData.Rows(row.Index).` with `row.`?

Comment: I updated the post with my current code for the issue I am having. the last selected row not getting updated to database.

Comment: Now it's just the last selected row which is not getting updated?

Comment: Nowhere in your loop block are you referencing the "row" variable. There's no point in having that loop — it just updates the same row every time.

Comment: The original code (second edit) referenced the row variable, but it was a little honky as it was: `For Each row In dgvData.SelectedRows` ... `dgvData.Rows(row.Index).Cells...`. I think there has been some refactoring, possibly moving even further away from a solution.

Comment: djv Correct only the last row is not getting updated. meaning if I select 20 rows 1 to 19 are updating to the database and row 20 does not.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just replace `dgvData.Rows(row.Index)` with `row` [mentioned by djv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126278/vb-net-datagridview-loop-though-selection-and-update-column-in-same-database-is#comment73336242_43126278)?

```
Private Sub UpdateData()

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvData.SelectedRows

        row.Cells(9).Value = 1

        row.Cells(10).Value = System.DateTime.Now

    Next

    SQL.DBDA.UpdateCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(SQL.DBDA).GetUpdateCommand
    SQL.DBDA.Update(SQL.DBDT)

End Sub
```

Other than this you might want to consider is it failed to update in SQL?

> 1. Did your `SQL.DBDA.Update` returns any error for the last line?
> 2. Can you know what SQL statement is the  `SQL.DBDA.Update` updates?